# Javascript Form Validation Problem

Tags: javascript, validation

i'm trying to put together some Javascript form validation to check that all fields have been completed before submitting.

So far i have this in my  tag, and the function for the first form field only:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validate(form) {
fail = vaildatecompany_name(preview.company_name.value)

if (fail =="" return true

else { alert(fail); return false }
}

function validatecompany_name(field) {
    if (field == "" return "No Company Name was entered. \n"
return ""
}
</script>
```

And the first field i'm trying to validate is:

```
<form action="jobpreview.php" name = "preview" method="post" form enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit = "return validate(this)">

<ul>
<li><label for = "company_name">Company Name</label>    
<input type="text" name="company_name"/>
</li>
```

Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong? It's not bringing up any alert when i submit the form with no entry in the field and is just going through as normal.

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is riddled with errors. You spelled your call to the `validatecompany_name` function wrong, your `if` statements aren't properly formed (errant opening bracket) and you don't pass the `form` variable properly (you treat `preview` and `form` interchangeably). This works, although it's not great code:

```
function validate(form){
  var fail = validatecompany_name(form.company_name.value);
    if (fail==""){
      return true;
    } else {
      alert(fail);
      return false;
    }
  }

function validatecompany_name(field){
  if (field == "") return "No Company Name was entered. \n";
  return "";
}
```

Comment: BTW you don't need the `\n` bit in your return from `validatecompany_name`, it doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: thanks Ben, this is actually copied from an O'Reilly book (but the typos on my behalf are terrible). Thanks for your time, this is working now. Thanks, Dan

Comment: can we at least do `return (field === "")?"No Company Name was entered":"";`

Comment: @Ben Poole Hi Ben, I spoke too soon, sort of. If i go on to add the same validation for the other fields in my form, it only seems to check the last one?

Comment: @Dan well you're using the same `fail` flag for everything I guess, so it's only as good as your last test. Like I say, this isn't great code, I'd be inclined to use something like the jquery.validate plugin myself -- a lot more powerful, and once you've got the hang of it, you'll use it again and again.

Comment: @mplungjan For sure. I'm just addressing the code provided. Personally I'd use jquery.validate :-)

Comment: @Ben Poole and @mplungjan i'll check that out. Thanks both for your help and patience. Dan

Answer (score 1):

You need closing parentheses on your if statements `if (BOOLEAN)`

Comment: Well that's a little embarrassing! OK, i've put the closing parentheses in but it's still not recognising the empty field on submit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Plain and un-fancy javascript validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(form) {
  var company_name=form.company_name;
  if (company_name.value=="") {
    alert("Please enter company name");
    company_name.focus();
    return false
  }
  var company_phone=form.company_phone;
  if (company_phone.value=="") {
    alert("Please enter company phone");
    company_phone.focus();
    return false
  }
  return true; // allow submission
}
</script>

<form action="jobpreview.php" method="POST" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate(this)">

<ul>
<li><label for = "company_name">Company Name</label>    
<input type="text" name="company_name"/>
</li>
.
.
.
</form>
```

If you need anything fancier than that, look at jQuery validation instead

Comment: @DAN You are welcome. My suggestion is far easier for you to maintain. It will show one error at a time and focus the field in error

Answer (score 0):

wat is this statement do proper closings... `if (field == "" return "No Company Name was entered. \n"` it should be like `if (field == "") return "No Company Name was entered. \n"`

and you cannot directly access form by name.. use `document.formname` or use the form object that you passed...

Comment: check the value of `preview.company_name.value` in alert... and comment all other codes... also try ` if (field.trim() == "") `